# If gravity travels at finite speed, when gravity from an object interacts with something far away, what direction is the force?

Tags: gravity

Does it get pulled towards the location that the object was when it originally emitted the gravitational force or where it is at the point in time when the force reaches the other object, or somewhere else altogether?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/458136/123208

Comment: Typically (although not always) the force points to the actual real time position, not to the delayed (retarded position). See this question (not the answers) for details: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/492870/does-static-gravity-follow-spacelike-geodesics